# Defining per request modification of layer order and symbology using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, dynamic-layer, rendering

My web app will (hopefully) use dynamic layers with symbols that are rendered dynamically, based on a user chosen attribute.  So far I am doing this by defining a UniqueValueRenderer, then passing these properties to a layer with LayerDrawingOptions.  My work so far is loosely based on [this example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/renderer_dynamic_layer_change_attribute.html).

I periodically add new layers to the map and then re-publish them with a Python script using ArcPy.  As far as I know, ArcPy does not provide a way to overwrite an existing map service (please correct me if I am wrong! )  So instead, I delete, then publish, the map service from scratch.

So here is my issue: to allow dynamic symbol rendering in my map services, I need to enable per request modification of the services, which I can do in Manager for the services on that server (see image below).  But, I have not found a way to do this with ArcPy.   Once the map services are re-published, as of now I need to then log into Manger and manually check the 'allow modification' checkbox, and also re-register the file gdb as a dynamic workspace.  I have several map services in this app that need to redner symbols dynamically.
(This question is also posted on ESRI's Geonet [here](https://community.esri.com/message/766420-define-per-request-modification-of-layer-order-and-symbology-using-arcpy)

[image: from ArcGIs for Server, Capabilities tab - I cannot find this functionality in ArcPy or when publishing an mxd manually]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, from ESRI support:

```
...
import xml.dom.minidom as DOM 
...

            analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'ARCGIS_SERVER', 
                                                      con, True, serviceFolder, summary, tags)


            doc = DOM.parse(sddraft)
            keyps = doc.getElementsByTagName('Key')
            for keyp in keyps:
                if keyp.firstChild.data == 'enableDynamicLayers': keyp.nextSibling.firstChild.data = 'true'


            newXML = wrkspc + service + r'_NEW.sddraft'
            f = open(newXML, 'w')
            doc.writexml(f)
            f.close()
```