# Creating web map with dynamically rendered symbols for multiple large datasets with ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, dynamic-layer, rendering

I am editing an existing ArcGIS Server (v10.2) / Javascript (3x) map-based web app, which has several dynamic map services, some of which contain over 50,000 points.

The new web app must be able to render symbology based on a user-chosen attribute.  The user can then choose the map layer to view with a slider, choose the map service with buttons, and choose the attribute with another set of buttons.

Currently, I have a demo set up which uses a UniqueValueRenderer to create the renderer to pass to a LayerDrawingOptions object, which then is assigned to a given layer in a dynamic map service.

This is working somewhat, but I have:

1. some map network load errors,
2. the symbols rendered look kind of jagged and pixelated,
3. I haven't yet found a way to set scale levels for the symbols, besides tying every zoom event to re-running all the functions I am using to render the points (ScaleDependentRenderer won't work), and
4. I need to re-publish the services every month to account for new layers, which I do now with a Python script - but I haven't found a way to set the necessary properties to allow modification of dynamic map services which I do now in Server Manager manually for my demos (I posted [define per request modification of layer order and symbology using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280649) about that concern)

Should I reconsider using feature services?

I was avoiding that because:

1. I didn't want to rewrite even more code and
2. from everything I've read, feature services can be sluggish when using services with many thousands of records.

If not that, is there any other way I can approach this problem?

At this time, I must use File GDBs and feature classes btw; so using a query based ArcSDE platform won't work.